# How to mock different value, of useLocation, for each test?

Tags: jestjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-component

My react component should do some change to the state according to the current location.

There is custom hook, that is called upon component loading.
In the hook there is a check of `useLocation().pathname` and the result in switch/case for the correct change.

Can this be Jest tested in one file/describe?
I tried to `jest.mock` `useLocation` but I just can't do it inside Jest describe...

This is the mock, currently out of the describe - and this works, but can't be changed from test to test:

```
const mockUseLocation = () => {
    jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
        useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
            pathname: '/val1'
        })
    }))
};
```

How can I test all the switch/case branches?

```
switch (pathname) {
   case 'val1':
       return 100;
   case 'val2':
       return 200;
   ...
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To go off of @skyboyer answer I got this working well using `renderHook`

The first argument is your hook you want to test and the second argument is your wrapper which I wraps `<MemoryRouter>`, `<Route>` around `children` prop.

```js
// test.js
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';

it('returns value from url query', () => {

    const wrapper: FC = ({ children }) => (
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[`/?user=authorized`]}>
        <Route path="*" />
        {children}
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useLocation(), { wrapper });

    expect(result.current).toBe('authorized');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is use [`MemoryRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md) instead mocking `useLocation`. Also this would be helpful if your component has `<Link>`(otherwise you will get the error "Link cannot be used outside the Router"). Also it allows you to check if navigation happens. So with such many benefits mocking `useLocation` directly does not have any value.

Take a [look into examples](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/testing) in official docs. It would be something alike:

```
test("current user is active in sidebar", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/users/2"]}>
      <YourComp />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
  expected(wrapper.find(User)).toHaveLength(2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of pathname by changing the value of this variable in the appropriate places in the tests.
For example:

```html
    let mockPATH = 'val1';
    jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
      useLocation: () => ({
        pathname: mockPATH
      })
    }));

    test('1st', () => {
      mockPATH = 'val2';
      //...
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
const locationMock = jest.fn();
const mockUseLocation = () => {
    jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
        useLocation: () => locationMock()
    }))
};
it('test1', () => {
    locationMock.mockReturnValue({
        pathname: '/val1'
    })
    expect()
})
it('test2', () => {
    locationMock.mockReturnValue({
        pathname: '/val2'
    })
    expect()
})
```

Hope it work for u ^^

Comment: You cannot use any mocks from outside jest.mock function scope.